# Можно ли изменить размер файла не теряя его свойств?

Tags: файлы

Допустим, есть какой-то произвольный файл, который имеет вес N КБ.

Можно ли изменить размер файла в большую сторону при этом не потеряв свойств файла(файл по прежнему открывается в программах, которых открывался ранее и не должен отображаться как-то иначе) или подобная манипуляция будет напрямую зависеть от формата над которым это будет делаться?

Например, дополнить незначащими `0`.

Comment: Произвольный - нет, ведь если добить нулями, например, текстовый файл, то текстовые редакторы будут вынуждены эти нули отображать

Comment: @andreymal, ну я так и подозревал собственно. Я нашел какую-то утилиту для винды Trunc. Попытался увеличить размер Excel-файла, так он при открытии сказал, что он поврежден и предложил его восстановить. После восстановления вернулся исходный размер.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вообще это странно, потому что как MS-CFB (он же doc, xls и т.д.) явно должен читаться с головы, и в заголовке указано где какие части лежат.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, проверил xls. Вот он корректно открывается после изменений и Excel ничего не говорит. Ранее пробовал формат 2007.

Comment: И JPG нормально открылся после наращивания размеров. Какой можно сделать вывод? Какие форматы не портятся?

Comment: @iluxa1810 формат 2007 это который xlsx? Ну так он внутри - ZIP, см. ниже.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, знаю. Хотелось бы знать какие файлы устойчивы к наращиванию и визуально содержимое не изменится и программа работы с файлами не вылетит с ошибкой.

Comment: EXE устойчив, если не подписан, например. А перечислять все - занятие не благодарное

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, можно только о популярных или сгруппировать по типам.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ваши популярные и наши популярные - разные популярные.

Answer (score 3):

Однозначно зависит от формата и от того, как формат читается. ZIP-файлы, к примеру, должны читаться с хвоста и добавление в хвост лишней информации может привести к нечитаемости. Но большинство софта кладут на спецификацию и читают ZIP с головы...

Answer (score 2):

Для изменения размера файла предусмотрена группа системных вызовов [**truncate**(2)](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=truncate&category=2). Одноимённая утилита позволит получить возможность вызывать их из командой строки. Например, следующая команда установит новый размер указанного файла равным 17 ТБ. Причём, если его размер был больше, содержимое будет урезано, если он был меньше, содержимое будет дополнено нулевыми байтами. Стоит отметить, что в последнем случае файл получится разреженным - в реальности на диске не будут храниться сполшные нули, а будет просто пометка в дескрипторе файла, что он содержит нулевые блоки. Это довольно эфективно.

```
truncate -s 17TB имя_файла.bin
```

Эта команда не изменяет все остальные свойства файла, она влияет только на содержимое и размер.

Comment: А для винды такое есть? Судя по ссылке-это линуес утилита

Comment: Потестил, программу Trunc для Windows и как писали ниже, изменение размера файла целиком зависит от самого файла. Например, TXT файл открылся после изменения размера, но EXCEL-файл начал ругаться на повреждение и предложил восстановить файл, после чего он стал нормального размера.